# How can I open favorites in chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks

My favorites from my hard drive always automatically opened in Chrome, but after I downloaded Opera they  opened there. I deleted Opera the same day but now they just open in Explorer, is there a way for them to automatically open in Chrome again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few options:

- Use Chrome’s built-in default-browser function (figure 1):

  1. Go to `chrome://settings`
  2. Scroll down to the *Default Browser* section
  3. Click the `[Make Google Chrome my default browser]` button
- Use Windows’ *Default Programs* function:

  - By file-type (figure 2):

    1. Open the *Control Panel*
    2. Select *Default Programs*
    3. Click *Associate a file type or protocol with a program*
    4. Select `.url` - *Internet Shortcut* in the list (bookmarks are `.url` files)
    5. Click the `[Change program…]` button
    6. Select Chrome in the list (you may need to expand the *Other Programs* list)
  - By program (figure 3):

    1. Open the *Control Panel*
    2. Select *Default Programs*
    3. Click *Set your default programs*
    4. Select *Chrome* in the list
    5. Click the `[Set this program as default]` to set it as the default for all of the types it supports or `[Choose defaults for this program]` to select which ones you want (for some reason, `.url` is not currently in the list)

---

**Figure 1**: Chrome’s default browser setting

[image: Chrome’s default browser setting]

**Figure 2**: Windows Default Programs setting by-type

[image: Windows Default Programs setting by-type]

**Figure 3**: Windows Default Programs setting by-program

[image: Windows Default Programs setting by-program]

Comment: @Selle, no problem; happy to help. I added a couple of more options which could come in handy in other situations in the future.